# TFS API: Retrieve changesets from main branch using VersionControlServer.QueryHistory

Tags: c#, tfs, ironpython, tfs-sdk

Given: TFS server with m > n changesets in team project X.

I am using TFS API and would like to get the n latest changesets of that branch.

I think I should be using [VersionControlServer.QueryHistory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb143089.aspx), but I don't understand how I can specify that I want all commits from main (default) branch of project X, but none from any other branch or from another team project in the collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want changes in  `$/Project/Some/Path`, then that should be the first argument to `QueryHistory`.  For example:

```
QueryHistory("$/Project/Some/Path", RecursionType.Full, 5);
```

Will show the most recent 5 changesets that affected `$/Project/Some/Path`.

Comment: I passed in 1 for item count for latest but unfortunately it isn't the latest, it's the first / oldest.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me - I had to use the QueryHistoryParameters overload and set SortAscending = false in order to get the latest changeset id and not the first changesetid.

```
var p = new QueryHistoryParameters(item.ServerItem, RecursionType.Full) {SortAscending = false};
var q = versionControl.QueryHistory(p);
var lastCs = q.FirstOrDefault();

if (lastCs != null)
    item.LastChangesetId = lastCs.ChangesetId;
```

Comment: The question is about filtering paths, not about sorting, no?